# Long delay in accurate voltages after ADC hasn't been used for a few days .

Tags: adc

I noticed something kind of funny when testing a ADS1262 32-bit Sigma-Delta ADC. For example, with gain set at the maximum of 32 PGA, with 20 mV applied, it took 11 minutes before the Arduino program printed 20 mV. This was after the unit hadn't been used for a few days. It starts printing at 0 mV then gradually climbs up to the correct applied voltage. If there is only a few minutes after a previous 20 mV reading, then there is no delay. If the gain is set lower, then there is no delay, even if it hadn't been used for several days. I'm a novice at this sort of thing and I'm just wondering why this delay is happening?

Comment: You're really going to have to give us a lot more details about your hardware and software. Otherwise, we'd just be speculating, which is pointless.

Comment: Most pro instrumentation calbration procedures specify an equipment warm-up period of around 20-30 minutes before making high-precision measurements or adjusting calibration. Clearly *something* in your system requires time to stabilize. Can't guess exactly what unless you edit the question to show details, like the circuit schematic and maybe an as-built photo.

Comment: That’s ridiculous, something is clearly wrong with your hardware or setup.

Comment: ::Boggle:: 32 Bit resolution, and a gain of 32.  What are you measuring?  Sound pressure level of gnat farts at 30 paces?

Comment: Put a DVM at the signal input - does it also take time to reach a value that is supposedly correct? What is your signal's source impedance? Show your circuit!!

Comment: Here, maybe this will help. I used it in a weigh scale I made. It works great. For example, I stood on the scale and it read 156.25 lbs. Then I picked up a 10 gram weight and it read 156.27 lbs. 10/454 = .022 lbs. I know that's not 32-bit precision but it still impressed me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at pages 19, 20 and 21 [of the .pdf](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1262.pdf) for this part, best accuracy is obtained at 25 C or 78 F. The drift in *gain* and *internal oscillator* combined can cause errors of several percent, even as it is trying to null them out.

It has always been a rule of thumb that ultra-accurate equipment may need 15 to 20 minutes to warm up and stabilize. During this time the ADC is constantly correcting for the changes in gain, offset and oscillator frequency. After being OFF for hours or days the internal temperature is unknown and not the same in every location of the main board.

This is why manufactures ask for a 15 to 20 minutes warm-up time during which the ADC may make hundreds of tiny corrections in gain and offset, plus the oscillator will reach a state of thermal balance, and then your readings should be spot on. 32 bits of resolution is one in four billion accuracy.

Comment: That makes me feel better, it would always hit the correct voltage in less than 15 minutes. It acts like there is something like a moving average being used, even though there is none in the program. I guess going for 32-bit precision is a whole different ballgame.